# MMO - Some NPCs controlled clientside?

Tags: mmo, npc

I'm making an online game and considering whether to handle certain NPCs clientside. Is this common?

For example I play Elder Scrolls Online and it seems basic townspeople NPC locations aren't quite synced up with my friends. I guess it makes sense if they're only wandering around in a set area for that to be handled clientside right?

So my question is, should I go with this method, or are there any good reasons why I shouldn't? Any examples of games that do, so I can see how they handle it?.

Answer (score 3):

In an MMO, every byte you send over the network literally costs you money. You can (and should) in fact calculate the impact each byte/player-second has on your monthly operating cost by looking up what you pay for bandwidth and traffic. So whenever you see a line of code which sends or receives a network message, imagine a price-tag sticking to it. Every time you can get away with *not* synchronizing something via network you are improving your profit margin.

But don't get too overzealous with moving game mechanics to the client, because everything you do on the client can be manipulated by hackers. If a cheater could get a tangible benefit by fudging it, keep it server-sided. People quitting your game because they are annoyed by cheaters is far more detrimental to your profits.

Now what does that mean for NPCs?

When the NPC is an irrelevant background detail which doesn't affect the game, then handling the NPCs client-sided is a completely reasonable approach. Most of the time, the players won't notice that they aren't synchronized. You can then even add a config option to control the density of background NPCs in cities to make the game run better on low-end hardware.

When the background NPC behaves in a predefined routine and does not react on the player's behavior at all (like a random person walking up and down the street without evading any PCs standing in the way), or that behavior is completely determined by network-synchronized player-actions (like birds flying away when someone walks past), you can in fact even keep the NPCs synchronized when they are client-sided. When each client simulates them in the same way, they will appear as if they were synchronized, even if not a single bit directly related to the NPC is sent via network.

The only situation where the players might notice that something is off is when players are able to interact with the NPCs in ways which influence their behavior. For example, a wandering NPC might stop their routine when a PC talks to them and continue walking when the dialog window is closed. When you don't synchronize this, you might get some bewildering situations when one player observes another. But that's more of a cosmetic problem with little gameplay impact. Remember your cost calculation and decide for yourself if it's worth it or not.

In other situations, Player-NPC interactions might be a relevant part of the multiplayer-experience. There might be party-quests where everyone in the party wants to see what the NPC is doing. Or players might be able to fight and kill NPCs. They would then expect other players to notice this and be affected by the NPC's demise. In that case, the NPC must be synchronized. If you can't afford it, you can not afford the whole feature.

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick Assumptions

Some things I'm assuming about the MMO:

- Exact NPC location is not important, just being close enough to interact
- There are a lot of NPCs (enough to make constantly updating their location cause network lag)
- Players interactions with the NPCs has little effect on the NPCs location (think escort quests, where an NPC follows a player)

With those, it may be a good idea to look at how Real Time Strategy (RTS) games handle individual unit positions.

#### RTS Games

Typically in an RTS game, each client receives the commands given by the other players, and then interpolates where the units should be based on that.

So if Player A sends his units to coordinates 100,100 at time 500, and the movement of all the units is deterministic, then any client in the session can recreate the position of the units at any given time.

This requires a couple of things in order for it to be effective in an RTS:

**Players must be in sync**
So when Player A issues a comment at time 500, and Player B issues a command at time 600, they must all be working on the same clock. If you've ever encountered a "players out of sync" issue or "players catching up" in older RTS, this is likely because their clocks were no longer the same.

**Results must be Deterministic**
Given just the command specifics and time, all clients should produce the same exact result. This is actually how replays work, they are just the commands sent, replayed as if you were in the game.
*Note: Some things don't have to be. In Starcraft 2, the effects after a unit dies may be different each time you play a recording. This is just aesthetics and has no impact on the game mechanically.*

#### For an MMO

Your server should still be the authority on where NPCs should be. Otherwise you'd run the risk of having a malicious client putting two NPCs near each other, and maybe taking advantage of trading with both at once, etc.

However, you can avoid updating the exact position of an NPC to every client (as if the NPC itself were a player) by providing more generalized information that the client can use to determine the NPC location.

If you have a tolerance for how close someone has to be to an NPC to interact, then you don't have to worry about **Syncing** players clocks as much as in an RTS. And when your server receives an interaction with an NPC, you can just check that the client is close enough to where the NPC should be.